# Sonata Field Type in Symfony Form

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I need to create a custom form but used within Symfony so I, therefore, have to create a Symfony form. However, I'd like to be able to use the functionality Sonta field types provide like `ModeListType::class`.

So far I have created a custom route on my admin, within the controller action I create a new Symfony form. The controller action then returns a view with the form which extends the Sonata base edit layout.

```
class ExampleController
{
    public function exampleAction(Request $request)
    {
        $order = new FooBar();

        $modelManager = $this->get('sonata.admin.manager.orm');

        $form = $this->createForm(ExampleType::class, $order, [
            'model_manager' => $modelManager,
        ]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            //
        }

        return $this->renderWithExtraParams('admin/test.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'action' => 'create',
            'object' => $order,
            'objectId' => null,
        ]);
    }
}
```

My form:

```
class ExampleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('job', ModelListType::class, [
                'model_manager' => $options['model_manager'],
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => FooBar::class,
        ]);

        $resolver->setRequired([
            'model_manager',
        ]);
    }
}
```

And my template:

```
{% extends 'bundles/SonataAdminBundle/CRUD/base_edit.html.twig' %}

{% import "@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_edit_form_macro.html.twig" as 
form_helper %}

{% block title %}
    Here
{% endblock %}

{% block sonata_tab_content %}
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-body">
                    {{ form(form) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This renders an input without the additional buttons like: List, Add, Delete. Clicking into the input also doesn't do anything, so it isn't treated as a Sonata input.

Any help on solving this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

As you override `{% block sonata_tab_content %}`, maybe you should try to put inside 
 `{% block formactions %}{{parent()}}{{% endblock %}`

```
{% block sonata_tab_content %}
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-body">
                    {{ form(form) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% block formactions %}
    {{parent()}}
{{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```